# Working with NSComboBox and controlTextDidEndEditing

Tags: macos, nscombobox

I have an NSComboBox and I'm trying to make it so that when the user selects a name, the other information (rate, rate type, and nationality) get automatically inputted. It works sometimes, but it causes an error at other times.

This code:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

    NSInteger index = [_nameBox indexOfItemWithObjectValue:[_nameBox stringValue]];
    _lblRate.stringValue =[[contents objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Rate"];

    NSInteger rateType =[[[contents objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"RateType"] integerValue];
    [_rateTypeSwitcher setSelected:YES forSegment:rateType];

    [_nationalityMenu selectItemWithTitle:[[contents objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"Nationality"]];

}
```

causes this error:

```
Ignoring exception raised in void run_cocoa_block(void *): *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]:
index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I make it not cause this error

Comment: Have you checked your contents array to make sure the index exists?

Comment: I'm 99% sure it exists...I'm getting the index from _nameBox which is an NSComboBox that gets populated by my contents array that in turn gets populated by a plist. I think there's a problem with my data types but I'm not experienced enough to pinpoint it myself.

Comment: Can you be 100% sure?